# Xcode 14.2 editor performance / stuttering

Tags: xcode

I'm currently on Xcode 14.2.  The text editor has some truly awful performance issues, where it frequently just freezes for several seconds while I'm typing.  It happens even when just moving the cursor around in a file.  I can type for 5 seconds or so, and then the cursor disappears and editing freezes for several seconds.  When it unfreezes, anything I typed while it was frozen appears.

The problem seems related to specific Xcode projects.  Some project it happens constantly, other projects, not at all.  It is incredibly annoying at best, and at worst, makes it nearly unusable.  Has anybody else encountered this?  Is there a fix?  Any idea what about a specific project would cause this?  I've tried all kinds of things:

- deleted DerivedData
- deleted my xcuserdata
- killed and restored Xcode
- rebooted my Mac
- turned off live issues

Nothing seems to help.  I am on a Mac Studio with an M1 Ultra chip, 128Gb Ram, so this is certainly not due to running on slow hardware.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the source of the problem is Xcode? I have had problems (with the same hardware) where completely unrelated third-party apps appeared to be causing very similar problems. My problems went away when I shut down these other apps (who shall remain nameless, but they are seemly innocuous, unobtrusive, apps, in the “how could that app possibly impact system performance like that?!” category).

Comment: I wondered about this same thing, but I feel like I've eliminated that possibility.  I've tried rebooting my Mac, and killed all other running apps once it has booted, and still see the problem.  Moreover, I can open one project and see the stuttering, and then open another project and the problem goes away.

Comment: Well, that’s promising. I'd create a copy of the offending project and start pruning stuff away until you find what you have to remove to resolve the problem…

Comment: @DaveL my coworker and I have been having this problem too. I'm on an M1 and have had it on MacOS 13 and macOS 14, with Xcode 14 and 15 respectively. I believe he only started to notice it with Xcode 15 (he's on an intel still). It's very annoying because the words you're typing/the code you're copying will just place itself somewhere random on the editor after it ends its ~4 second freeze. I hate native app development.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd update on this in case it's helpful to anybody else.  I had Xcode running under Rosetta, and tried turning that off.  The problem mostly went away.  It's not perfect, but the performance is so much better that it's no longer an issue.